# Сlass hierarchy - class has no member

Tags: c++

I have the next class hierarchy:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    void SetParent(BaseClass* ptr) { parent = ptr; }
    BaseClass* GetParent() { return parent; };
protected:
    BaseClass* parent;
};

class ClassFirst : public BaseClass
{
public:
    void UniqueMethod() { }
};

class ClassSecond : public BaseClass
{
};
```

I'm trying to do next:

```
ClassFirst* first = new ClassFirst;
ClassSecond* second = new ClassSecond;
second->SetParent(first);
second->GetParent()->UniqueMethod();
```

But I get an error:
`Class "BaseClass" has no member "UniqueMethod".`
So how do I access the parent?

Comment: `BaseClass* GetParent()` returns a pointer to a `BaseClass` which has no UniqueMethod() function.

Comment: If you need to access it this way, then you need to have that as a `virtual` function on the `BaseClass` class. It could even be a dummy function that doesn't do anything, but allows it to be overridden. As far as C++ is concerned, `ClassFirst` is completely irrelevant when talking about `BaseClass`, and only functions for that class can be accessed. That `ClassFirst` defines new functions is great, but only when talking about `ClassFirst*`.

Comment: If you want to access it through the `BaseClass` interface, it must be a (virtual) member of `BaseClass`. If it shouldn't be a part of `BaseClass`, you should probably rethink your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightforward method would be to use a cast. Currently, your `parent` member within `BaseClass` does not have a `UniqueMethod()` method. However, `ClassFirst` does. Since we know that `second->GetParent()` is actually an object of type `ClassFirst`, we can perform a cast to that type of object, and do this:

```
ClassFirst* temp = static_cast<ClassFirst*>(second->GetParent());
temp->UniqueMethod();
```

If you don't know if the `parent` object will actually be an object of the class with the `UniqueMethod()` method (it could be of type `ClassSecond`, which does not have it), you can do it this way:

```
ClassFirst* temp = dynamic_cast<ClassFirst*>(second->GetParent());
if(temp) temp->UniqueMethod();
```

[Dynamic cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) will return nullptr if it is not the correct type. [Static cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) will throw an error.